# Jquery get the value of the most recent instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I get the value of the class called userID from this instance of the form?  I can't serialize the form because the form itself doesn't have any unique identifiers.

```
<form method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="userID" class="userID" value="<? echo $id; ?>" >
       <input type="hidden" name="imageID" class="imageID" value="<? echo $row['newest_image']; ?>" >
       <input type="button" style="margin-top:10px" name="delete_standard" class="delete_standard_btn" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Currently I am using

```
var image_id = $(this).prev('.imageID').val();
var user_id = $(this).prev('.userID').val();
```

This gives me the imageID ok but not the userID, if I swap the hidden inputs round in the form I am able to get the userID but not the imageID.

Comment: How do you currently reference the `form` - how is "it" called from "this instance"? Having unique identifiers is not a necessity.

Comment: what is `this` in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `prevAll('.userID')` rather than `prev('.userID')`. [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) only looks at the immediate preceding sibling, [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll) looks at *all* preceding siblings and returns them in order (nearest first). Since the nearest is the first, calling `val()` on it will give you the value of the nearest matching sibling.

E.g.:

```
var image_id = $(this).prevAll('.imageID').val();
var user_id = $(this).prevAll('.userID').val();
```

Comment: perfect, thanks.  Will accept when it will let me :)

Answer (score 0):

If $(this) is the form, then, use .find().

```
$('.userID', this).val();
// or
$(this).find('.userID').val();
```

If it is the button element, use .prevAll() instead of .prev().

```
$(this).prevAll('.userID').first().val();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you submit a form with jQuery, your context `this` is set to the current form element.
So you can do something like that:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        image_id = $this.find('.imageID'),
        user_id = $this.find('.userID');
}
```